# Trying to get OAuth2 token from Azure server from Java

Tags: java, spring-boot, oauth-2.0, spring-security-oauth2, spring-oauth2

Hi have these below details which are working fine from Postman but I need to retrieve the Oauth2 token from Java.

1. ClientId : clientid-abcd-bcda-xxxx-bbbbc-bbbbsjhk
2. clientsecret: client-secret-xxxx-bgdj-jbkjg-dddff
3. callbackurl:https://somecalbackurl.to.access.receive.an.authorization.code
4. accesstokenUlr: https://some AccessToken Url Url
5. AuthUrl: https://somAuthUrl
6. Service AccUserName & Password

public static void main(String[] args) throws OAuthProblemException {

```
String clientId = "clientid-abcd-bcda-xxxx-bbbbc-bbbbsjhk";
String clientSecret = "client-secret-xxxx-bgdj-jbkjg-dddff ";
String accessTokenUrl = "https://someaccess.token/guhns87-abcd-3000-b245-62c1d05/oauth2/";
String authUrl = "https://someauthurl/4866523-62c1d05b6b3a/oauth2/";
String callbackUrl = "https://callbackurl.com/";
```

String encodedValue = getBase64Encoded(clientId, clientSecret);

```
OAuthClient client = new OAuthClient(new URLConnectionClient());
try {
    OAuthClientRequest request = 
           OAuthClientRequest.tokenLocation(accessTokenUrl)
           .setGrantType(GrantType.AUTHORIZATION_CODE)                 
           .setRedirectURI("callbackurl")                  
           .buildBodyMessage();
    
    request.addHeader("Authorization", "Basic "+ encodedValue);
    //OAuthClientRequest.authorizationProvider(OAuthProviderType.MICROSOFT);
    
    OAuthJSONAccessTokenResponse token = client.accessToken(request,OAuth.HttpMethod.POST,OAuthJSONAccessTokenResponse.class);
    String finalToken=token.getAccessToken();
    
 System.out.println(finalToken);
 
} catch (OAuthSystemException e) {
    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

}
public static String getBase64Encoded(String id,String password) {
return Base64.getEncoder().encodeToString((id +":"+ password).getBytes(StandardCharsets.UTF_8));
}

From this above I need to retrieve Access token and used to call to further API with credentials to get the data. but facing error as below

uri='https://somewhere.net/error?code=900144', state='null', scope='null', redirectUri='null', responseStatus=400, parameters={}}

not sure where I am missing.

Comment: Do you need a scope for this, its usually set as the resource url (auth url for you probably) with /.default on the end, eg authUrl/.default.
That worked for me with azure resources before
Also try hitting the url in insomnia / postman client with those set as params and check that also

Comment: @JackBranch scope is empty in postman

Comment: For me it was just a pram called scope within the request you send, i think you have to send it in your request like so scope=myurl/.default.
This was the case for ad login, graph login etc for me

Comment: no luck still same error